# Does creating a boto3 session trigger an http request to the AWS API?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Does creating a boto3 session trigger an http request to the AWS API?

Or is it only when a resource operation takes place?

Comment: No, it doesn't. A boto3 session is a local collection of config data e.g. credentials, region etc. There's no interaction with an AWS backend API. To actually invoke an AWS API you need to create a boto3 client or resource with the session and then call the various methods on that client or resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. A boto3 session is a local collection of config data and state e.g. credentials, region etc. There's no interaction with an AWS backend API. To actually invoke an AWS API you need to create a boto3 client or resource with the session and then call the various methods on that client or resource.

The [reference documentation for Session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) shows that it does expose methods that could cause API calls to AWS but I don't believe these are called (unless *you* decide to call them). They include:

- get_available_partitions
- get_available_regions

You can review the [source code for Session](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/session.py) to see that it appears to be simply a container for config and state. Here is the start of the inline documentation for the class:

> A session stores configuration state and allows you to create service
> clients and resources.